# Как считать информацию из mp3 файла на java?

Tags: java, mp3

Стоит задача создать каталогизатор mp3-файлов. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие библиотеки нужно подключать и как, собственно, происходит сам процесс вытягивания инфы?

Интересуют такие моменты, как исполнитель, название трека, альбом, длина трека и т.д.

Comment: Под инфой вы подразумеваете метаданные?

Comment: Да, интересует такие моменты, как исполнитель, название трека, альбом, длина трека и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Можете воспользоваться вот этой библиотекой https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic

Получить информацию с ее помощью достаточно просто:

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("SomeMp3File.mp3");
if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
  ID3v1 id3v1Tag = mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
  System.out.println("Track: " + id3v1Tag.getTrack());
  System.out.println("Artist: " + id3v1Tag.getArtist());
  System.out.println("Title: " + id3v1Tag.getTitle());
  System.out.println("Album: " + id3v1Tag.getAlbum());
  System.out.println("Year: " + id3v1Tag.getYear());
  System.out.println("Genre: " + id3v1Tag.getGenre() + " (" + id3v1Tag.getGenreDescription() + ")");
  System.out.println("Comment: " + id3v1Tag.getComment());
}
```

Зависимость для maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mpatric</groupId>
  <artifactId>mp3agic</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) [библиотека](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jd3lib/)

2) Последние 128 байт файла mp3 содержат метаданные. Структура:

Song title  30 characters
Artist  30 characters
Album   30 characters
Year    4 characters
Comment 30 characters
Genre   1 byte
Но это для ID3v1,у ID3v2 структура сложнее

3) так же к прочтению не помешает [тык](http://blog.bjrn.se/2008/10/lets-build-mp3-decoder.html), [тык](https://habrahabr.ru/post/103635/)